# Exported Uv maps have no color (Fixed)

Tags: uv, export, edit-mode

Whenever I export Uv maps from blender and open them in any program like unity and gimp, they miss all color and only have the basic Uv outlines for the object, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: UVMaps are meant to export UV layouts not color information, what you want is to export textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using *Export UV Layout* function - this just exports an image containing a wire so you know where to paint the texture.

If you already have the texture and just want to save it, open it in UV/Image Editor and press <kbd>F3</kbd>.